# An array of a value not being properly displayed in the label

Tags: ios, text, xcode8, userdefaults

I am using xcode 8 and swift 3. I have made a mini game where you have to answer questions as fast as you can. You are timed by a stopwatch. I have the code to actually store the times(eg 23 seconds) but instead of storing the time, it replaces it with "Label". My stopwatch label is called down and the `label` that displays the values is called `resultLabel` I have been told the problem is when i set the text of the label. Any ideas on where i need to fix it. An example is ["Label", "Label", "Label"]

Stopwatch code:

```
if timerSecond != nil {

            timerSecond?.invalidate()
            timerSecond = nil


        } else {


            timerSecond = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
                self.currentTime += 1
                let minutePortion = String(format: "%02d", self.currentTime / 60 )
                let secondsPortion = String(format: "%02d", self.currentTime % 60 )
                self.down.text = "\(minutePortion):\(secondsPortion)"
            }
        }
```

extension for User Defaults:

```
extension UserDefaults {
var timesSecond: [String] {
        get {
            if let times = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "times") as? [String] {
                return times
            } else {
                return []
            }
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "times")
        }
    }
}
```

Button code to display the array of values:

```
let arrayOfTimes = UserDefaults.standard.timesSecond

        resultLabel.text = "\(arrayOfTimes)"
```

code for storing the data:

```
UserDefaults.standard.timesSecond.append(resultLabel.text!)
```

Comment: show us the code where you add the time to the array of times

Comment: What value are you getting back from UserDefaults.standard.timesSecond?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ , this is the code in my view DidAppear 
                       
                       
                       UserDefaults.standard.timesSecond.append(resultLabel.text!)

Comment: @iCyberPaul, the values i am getting is, all the times(23 secs, 12 secs) and storing all of them as an  array. It is Milans original code

Comment: Just figured it out!

Comment: Can you share the solution.

Comment: I had to add UserDefaults.standard.times.append(score.text!)
to my save score button, then i added                                                             if  let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "times") as? String {
            
            resultLabel.text = x
            
            
        }
    }
to the viewDidAppear

Comment: Thanks MilanNosáľ and iCyberPaul for your help!